# How do I achieve through Jboss Resteasy interceptors?

Tags: api, jboss, resteasy, interceptor

I am working on the Jboss Resteasy API to implement the REST services on Jboss server.I am new to this area. Can someone help me out here...

There is a Rest Service method with custom annotation(VRestAuto) like below.

```
@POST
@Produces("text/json")
@Path("/qciimplinv")
@Interceptors(VRestInterceptor.class)
public String getInvSummary(@VRestAuto("EnterpriseId") String enterpriseId,String circuitType){
   ....
   businessMethod(enterpriseId,circuitType);
   ....
}
```

@VRestAuto annotation tell us 'enterpriseId' value is available in the user session.

User pass the circuitType alone as the POST parameter in the Rest Client tool.Should ideally read the enterpriseid from session and invoke the Rest service with these two parameters(enterpriseid,circuitType).

To achieve the above functionality, implemented the Interceptors class (VRestInterceptor) like below:

```
public class VRestInterceptor implemnets PreProcessInterceptor,AcceptedByMethod  {
public boolean accept(Class declaring, Method method) {
      for (Annotation[] annotations : method.getParameterAnnotations()) {
             for (Annotation annotation : annotations) {
                 if(annotation.annotationType() == VRestAuto.class){
                     VRestAuto vRestAuto = (VRestAuto) annotation;
                    return vRestAuto.value().equals("EnterpriseId");
                 }
             }
         }
         return false;
     }
            Override
     public ServerResponse preProcess(HttpRequest request, ResourceMethod method)
             throws Failure, WebApplicationException {  ......} 
}
```

I was able to verify the VRestAuto annotation in the accept method. But in the preProcess Method, how can I call the REST method with two parameters(enterpriseid, circuitType)?

if these interceptors are not suits, Are there any other interceptors best to this functionality?

Your help is highly appreciated .

Answer (score 1):

Why not forget setting the enterpriseId value when the method is called and instead just inject the HttpServletRequest and use that to grab the session and value?

```
@POST
@Produces("text/json")
@Path("/qciimplinv")
public String getInvSummary(String circuitType, @Context HttpServletRequest servletRequest) {
   HttpSession session = servletRequest.getSession();

   String enterpriseId = session.getAttribute("EnterpriseId").toString();

   ....
   businessMethod(enterpriseId,circuitType);
   ....
}
```